# Select data.frame rows by a logical condition: select multiple of 3 rows

Tags: r

I want to select strong textrows from a main data.frame based on this logical condition: select multiple of 3 rows  Let's suppose that I have data frame like

```
sample    value
     
1           1 

2          10 

3         100 

4           8        

5          80          

6         800          

7          12          

8         120          

9         1200          

10          11          

11         110          

12        1100          

13           4         

14          40          

15         400         

16           0         

17           0         

18           0        

19           6         

20          60         

21         600
```

I want to get a nwe data.frame composed of multiple of 3 rows 3)100 6)800 9)1200 12)1100...

How to?

Comment: Could you clarify what your new data.frame will look like in the end? You mentioned "multiple of 3 rows 3)100 6)800" - what should this look like exactly? Could you edit your question and make another data.frame similar to your first one that explicitly shows your desired result?

Comment: Do you want to select only rows where the values in `sample` are multiples of 3? If so, you can use the integer division operator `%/%`, which divides with no remainder. Imagine that your data.frame is `d` and has columns `sample` and `value`. Rows where `sample` is a multiple of 3 can be found like so: `d[d$sample / 3 == d$sample %/% 3, ]` or with dplyr: `dplyr::filter(d, sample / 3 == sample %/% 3)`